# Trying to add WooCommerce booking start date to write into database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Booking plugin and I need to hook into the booking, get the start date and import that into the database as a UNIX timestamp format.

This is the code I am using to try and get the start date:

```
$wcBooking = new WC_Booking( $original_order_id );
$current_timestamp = strtotime($wcBooking->get_start_date());
```

I am trying to get it using the WC_Booking class, I have pasted this class here http://pastebin.com/JGjDKyrj

When this code is running, it's just putting the following in the database:

> 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: echo this `$wcBooking->get_start_date()` so you see what you are actually getting from that call. Its probably not what you expected it to be

Comment: Why dont you read the code for `get_start_date()` the issue is blatantly obvious

Comment: I am adding this code as a function in another plugin, unfortunately its not a case of simply echoing it

Comment: If you would care to share that would be great please - thats what i'm here for :)

Comment: I have never been in the same timezone as woocommerce and its obvious to me so why cant you take a quick _butchers hook_ at the code and work it out for yourself

Comment: Thanks for being so constructive and helpful @RiggsFolly

Comment: I've literally been on this for ages, it's really not obvious to me...

Answer (score 1):

Got it the following code works:

```
$wcBooking = new WC_Booking( $original_order_id );
            $dataString = $wcBooking->get_start_date( 'Y-m-d', 'H:i:s' );
            $current_timestamp = strtotime($dataString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format in MySQL date format, if the column is DATETIME type, MYSQL is expecting `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format, for four digit year, two-digit month and day, and hour and minute and seconds. When it's not receiving this, it replaces with UNIX epoch time as you describe.

One line change, where you reformat in correct date format from UNIX time:

`$current_timestamp = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($wcBooking->get_start_date()) );`

You may also set date/time parameters in `get_start_date()` like:

`$current_timestamp = $wcBooking->get_start_date( 'Y-m-d', 'H:i:s' );`

Comment: Thanks, it's now coming into the database as 1970-01-01 00:32:50

Comment: On the class in the pastebin it says

Comment: /**
  * Returns booking end date
  * @return string Date formatted via date_i18n
  */

Comment: Showing as 1970-01-01 00:00:00 again :(